# Factor fields, is this reasoning correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let H = $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/<x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x+1>.$ Find the smallest
>   field F such that $H \subset F. $

We can factor $x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x+1$ as $(x^2+x+2)^2$, so it is not irreducible. However, since it does not have any zeroes in $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ it does not have any linear factors so it can't be reduced any further. Thus $x^2+x+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

My line of thinking is that now $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/<x^2+x+2>$ will be a field, (because irreducible polynomial) and that this field will contain the original, since the ideal $<x^2+x+2>$ includes $(x^2+x+2)^2$.

However, I am having some trouble actually convincing myself that this is indeed true. Am I going about this in a proper way?

Comment: I guess you mean $\mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^4+2x^3+2x^2+x+1)$?

Comment: Since $H$ is not integral, there is no field $F$ that can contain $H$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Your claim is not true in general. There are lots of rings that are not fields, but are contained in fields. One of the easiest examples are the integers that are contained in the field of rational numbers.

Comment: @user44400 Thanks. I changed my comment. It now makes sense.

Comment: @user44400 No, I mean Z3! 
@

Comment: What is Z3 for you? $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$? This is just $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: Well yes, by $\mathbb{Z}_3$ I mean the field on {0,1,2} which is indeed Z/3Z.

Comment: Your $H$ has zero-divisors and can thus never be embedded into a field.

Comment: $\overline{X^2+X+2}$ is a zero divisor of $H$...